# Work around for re-rendering new state in react

Tags: reactjs

```
      import React, {Component} from 'react';
      import Square from './components/board.js';

      const spaceArr = ()=> {
         const arr =[];
         for (var i=0; i<20; i++){
         arr.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*(400-0)));
         }
         return arr;
      };


      class App extends Component{

        constructor(){
          super();
          this.state={
            spaces: spaceArr(),
            array : new Array(400).fill(false)
          } ;
          var th = this;
          this.state.spaces.map(function(value){  
          th.state.array.splice(value, 1, true)});
            this.click= this.click.bind(this);
          }

          componentDidMount(){
            this.setState({array: this.state.array})
          }

          click(i, live) {  
            this.state.array[i]= !live;
            var array = this.state.array;
            this.setState({array: array}, function(){
             console.log(array[i]) 
          })
          }


         render(){

           var th = this;
          return (
             <div>
               <div className='backboard'>
               <div className='board'>
                 {this.state.array.map(function(live, index){

                   return <Square key={index} living={live} clicker=  
                     {th.click.bind(this, index, live)}/>
                   })

                  }
                </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           )
          }
         }

         export default App;
```

I am trying to figure out how to re-render the updated state change after setState. the click event is a handler that is passed to a child component. the updated array should re-render an updated rendering of child components.

Comment: can you share your code where you have define the `click` function?

Comment: @Md.EstiakAhmmed ok, updated

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
 click(i, live) {  
      var array = this.state.array;
      array[i]=!live
      this.setState({array:array}, function(){
         console.log(this.state.array[i]) 
      })
  }
```

Comment: I did a few variations, but alas to no avail. it is still not re-rendering with the updated state chnage, although it is logging it as occurring in the console.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't mutate this.state directly as mentioned in [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html).
Use concat for getting a new array before setting the new state:

```
click(i, live) {  
  var newArray = this.state.array.concat();
  newArray[i]!=live
  this.setState({array: newArray}, function(){
     console.log(this.state.array[i]);
  })
}
```

Comment: makes sense but still not re-rendering

Answer (score 1):

on your return it should be,

```
return (<Square key={index} living={live} 
  clicker= {th.click.bind(th, index, live)}/>
});
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks everyone for trying to answer. My mistake was in setting the "live" attribute in the child component as a state. I instead just passed it as a props directly to the render method conditionals, and that has resolved the issue entirely. also, I think in solving asynch setState method, a good bypass is changing state by setting it to a callback within the property eg.(setState({prop: someFunction()})). Anyway, thanks again.